# Картинка в Image из базы данных в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Нужно по выбранном значении в combobox "Art" в image "Image" отобразить картинку из базы данных mssql "Table", при выборе другого значения картинка должна меняться.

```
private void Art_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=...");
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE …", connection);

            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader datareader = command.ExecuteReader();
            datareader.Read();

            int bLength = (int)datareader.GetBytes(6, 0, null, 0, int.MaxValue);

            byte[] bBuffer = new byte[bLength];
            datareader.GetBytes(6, 0, bBuffer, 0, bLength);

            connection.Dispose();

            MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(bBuffer);
            
        }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как закончить реализацию данной задачи.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9564425/12888024

Comment: Или даже так, с привязкой данных https://stackoverflow.com/a/8432900/12888024